# How to approach MySQL Procedures and Functions

Tags: mysql

I'm an experience MS SQL developer. Coming from mssql to mysql is a bit frustrating for me. In order to be short, I would like to ask how some standard mssql tasks are accomplished in mysql. The very first thing that i noticed is that mysql function cannot return a result set. It is trivial in mssql to use function like this.
In pseudo code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_test()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT * FROM SomeTable
```

And then:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN fn_test() AS fn ON t1.condition = fn.condition
```

That is not possible in mysql, the approach that I find after an hour of researches was to create a procedure instead, within create a temp table, insert values in it, after the procedure is executed the table remains 'alive' on connection level, and then drop the table. This seems to be an overhead for me. So the questions here are:

1) If they are lets say 500 connections, and all this connections execute lets say 2-3 procedures using the approach that i mentioned, this means 500x1 temp tables x2 procedures calls = 1000 temp tables. How the server will handle this technique?

2) Is this the only approach, and are there any better then this one for example by views or something?

3) What kind of approach do you choose for this particular scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against ever expecting a certain vendors procedural extensions in another vendors product. I would bet that no PL-SQL exists either.. In fact I know it does not exist. I would also add that MS makes it much easier than some others in the DB world.

However, MySQL has the concept of User Defined Functions or UDF's.. Read more [HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-function-udf.html) Granted a temp table can be a great option, but in your case you may need to create your own function.

Here is another reference to MySQL Functions and Operators [HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/functions.html)

EDIT:
To answer your question, you would have to use a Stored Proc to return a table in MySQL.

```
DELIMITER $$

 CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `ret_table`(OUT my_ErrMessage   VARCHAR(200))
 BEGIN
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
 BEGIN
SET my_ErrMessage = 'Error in procedure ret_table';
 END;

 SELECT * FROM SomeTable;
END
```

I will add that 500+ connections and 1000+ temp tables is not that out of the ordinary in DB environments unless your temp tables are very large. Also, a return table via a function call is not much different than a temp table as far as memory is concerned. You don't mention any functional requirements above only a theoretical problem of not being able to return a table via a function call.

Lastly, I am not anti MS at all, but in using their dev tools in Windows it is very easy to blur the lines between what work you would normally do in the application layer and what work you do in the Database. MySQL is not going to be MS SQL Server or Oracle, but it will do what you need. You just have to go about problem solving differently.

I would do this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS someTab1 AS (SELECT * FROM SomeTable);

SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN someTab1 AS st1 ON t1.condition = st1.condition
```

I know this is not a fn() but how is selecting into a temp table different from, returning a table via a fn() when it comes to memory usage or performance. If you need error handling wrap it all  in a Stored Proc.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but still this is not the answer i was looking for, please check the Questions 1),2),3). Its seems to me, by using UDF's i can't accomplish the task that I was aimed for:
1: The UDF's can't return table, that i can join later on with another table.
2: The approach with the procedure calls and temp tables still remains like the only option, but what about the performance using this technique?

Comment: Your question can't really be answered in an online programming forum outside of pointing to reference documentation. I did edit my answer with how I would do what you want.